# Using do.call with dplyr standard evaluation version

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I get a `do.call` with a variable list of arguments and functions to work with the standard evaluation version of `summarise_` in dplyr?

```
## Some sample data, function, and variables to interpolate
set.seed(0)
dat <- data.frame(a=runif(10), b=runif(10))
fn <- function(x, y) IQR(x / y, na.rm = TRUE)
funs <- list(fn="fn")
targs <- list("a", "b")
```

This is the `lazyeval::interp` I'm trying to make work

```
library(dplyr)
interp(~do.call(fn, xs), .values=list(fn=funs$fn, xs=targs))
# ~do.call("fn", list("a", "b"))
```

but it doesnt work,

```
dat %>%
  summarise_(out = interp(~do.call(fn, xs), .values=list(fn=funs$fn, xs=targs)))
```

Expected result

```
dat %>%
  summarise(out = do.call(fn, list(a, b)))
#        out
# 1 1.084402
```

If I add in some print statements, I know the problem is that the "a" and "b" aren't being interpreted properly, but I haven't been able to figure out how to quote them properly.

```
fn <- function(x, y) { print(x); print(y); IQR(x / y, na.rm = TRUE) }
dat %>%
  summarise_(out = interp(~do.call(fn, xs), fn=funs$fn, xs=targs))
# [1] "a"
# [1] "b"
# Error: non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Comment: I may be missing something (having never understood the appeal of `interp` constructs), but `dat %>% summarise(out = do.call(fn, unname(.[unlist(targs)])))` works to get the `list(a,b)` or `dat %>% summarise(out = do.call(fn, lapply(targs, function(x) .[[x]])))`

Comment: Do you really need the `do.call` here? Couldn't it just be something like `dat %>% summarise_(out = interp(~f(x,y), f = as.name(funs$fn), x = as.name(targs[[1]]), y = as.name(targs[[2]])))`?

Comment: Could you clarify the situation about not knowing the number of arguments the functions take?  It's possible someone could help you come up with a way to solve that problem without `do.call` if you give an example of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @TheTime I was thinking working with the `eval(parse(text=...))` paradigm might work, making `targs = "list(a, b)"`, but that creates the same problem where `a` is still interpreted as `"a"`.  This thing of sometimes using strings without the quotes is the bane of R and creates endless problems.

Comment: I don't understand why the answer supplied by @Frank doesn't work.  Where should `group_by` be added to break it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `targs` argument needs to be a `call` class. The variables in the `call` (`a` and `b`) need to be a `name` class. All this is done in the second (and third) line below. `?call`, `?as.name`, and `?is.language` might make the line more understandable.

```
dat <- data.frame(a=runif(10), b=runif(10), grp=rep(1:2, each=5))
targs_quoted = do.call(call, c("list", lapply(targs, as.name)), quote=TRUE)
# In hardcoded form, targs_quoted = quote(list(a, b))
dat %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  summarise_(out = interp(~do.call(fn, xs), 
                          .values=list(fn=funs$fn, xs=targs_quoted)))

# Source: local data frame [2 x 2]
#     
#       grp       out
#     (int)     (dbl)
#  1     1  1.0754497
#  2     2  0.9892201
```

`dplyr`'s "nse" (non-standard evaluation) [vignette](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/vignettes/nse.Rmd) was very helpful here. I found that the `.` always referred to the entire table, not the grouped table. That's why some of the recommendations in the comments didn't "work" as wanted.