# Using standard evaluation and do_ to run simulations on a grid of parameters without do.call

Tags: r, design-patterns, simulation, tidyverse

**Goals**

I want to use dplyr to run simulations on grids of parameters. Specifically, I'd like a function that I can use in another program that

- gets passed a data.frame
- for every row calculates some simulation using each column as an argument
- also is passed some extra data (e.g., initial conditions)

Here's my approach

```
require(dplyr)
run <- function(data, fun, fixed_parameters, ...) {
   ## ....
   ## argument checking
   ##

   fixed_parameters <- as.environment(fixed_parameters)
   grouped_out <- do_(rowwise(data), ~ do.call(fun, c(., fixed_parameters, ...)))
   ungroup(grouped_out)
 }
```

This works. For example, for

```
growth <- function(n, r, K, b) {
  # some dynamical simulation
  # this is an obviously-inefficient way to do this ;)
  n  + r - exp(n) / K - b - rnorm(1, 0, 0.1)
}
growth_runner <- function(r, K, b, ic, ...) {
  # a wrapper to run the simulation with some fixed values
  n0 = ic$N0
  T = ic$T
  reps = ic$reps
  data.frame(n_final = replicate(reps, {for(t in 1:T) {
                                          n0 <- growth(n0, r, K, b)
                                        };
                                        n0})
  )
}
```

I can define and run,

```
   data <- expand.grid(b = seq(0.01, 0.5, length.out=10),
                       K = exp(seq(0.1, 5, length.out=10)),
                       r = seq(0.5, 3.5, length.out=10))
   initial_data = list(N0=0.9, T=5, reps=20)
   output <- run(data, growth_runner, initial_data)
```

**Question**

Even though this seems to work, I wonder if there's a way to do it without `do.call`. (In part because of [issues with do.call](http://rpubs.com/hadley/do-call2).)

I really am interested in a way to replace the line `grouped_out <- do_(rowwise(data), ~ do.call(fun, c(., fixed_parameters, ...)))` with something that does the same thing but without `do.call`. **Edit:** An approach that somehow avoids the performance penalties of using `do.call` outlined at the above link would also work.

**Notes and References**

- [this question on do.call and standard evaluation in dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33714341/using-do-call-with-dplyr-standard-evaluation-version) is helpful, but I'm looking for a way to avoid do.call if possible
- dplyr's [nse vignette](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/vignettes/nse.Rmd) was helpful in writing this; and makes me think `.values` could work in place of `do.call`

Comment: FWIW it sounds exactly like `plyr::mdply`. Unfortunately the two packages are rather incompatible.

Comment: dang, I'd never found that part of `plyr`! thanks for the pointer

Comment: I think you probably want `purrr::invoke_rows` for this, it's the modern equivalent of `mdply`.

http://rpackages.ianhowson.com/cran/purrr/man/by_row.html

Comment: thanks @shorpy that looks super promising

Answer (score 5):

I found it a little tricky to follow your code, but I think this is equivalent.

First I define a function that does the computation you're interested in:

```
growth_t <- function(n0, r, K, b, T) {
  n <- n0

  for (t in 1:T) {
    n <- n + r - exp(n) / K - b - rnorm(1, 0, 0.1)
  }
  n
}
```

Then I define the data that you want to vary, including a "dummy" variable for reps:

```
data <- expand.grid(
  b = seq(0.01, 0.5, length.out = 5),
  K = exp(seq(0.1, 5, length.out = 5)),
  r = seq(0.5, 3.5, length.out = 5),
  rep = 1:20
)
```

Then I can feed it into `purrr::pmap_d()`. `pmap_d()` does a "parallel" map - i.e. it takes a list (or data frame) as input, and calls the function varying all the named arguments for each iteration. The fixed parameters are supplied after the function name.

```
library(purrr)
data$output <- pmap_dbl(data[1:3], growth_t, n0 = 0.9, T = 5)
```

This really doesn't feel like a dplyr problem to me, because it's not really about data manipulation.

Comment: thanks! fair point re dplyr, It started with `dplyr::do`. but given expanded tooling for tidy data, and especially the direction you're heading with `purrr` (eg, http://stackoverflow.com/q/35505187/4598520 ), I agree it's probably better described as tidy data problem

Answer (score 1):

The below avoids using `do.call` and presents the output in the same way as the OP.

First, replace the parameters of the function with a vector that you'll pass in - this is what you'll pass through using apply.

```
growth_runner <- function(data.in, ic, ...) {
  # a wrapper to run the simulation with some fixed values
  n0 = ic$N0
  T = ic$T
  reps = ic$reps
  data.frame(n_final = replicate(reps, {for(t in 1:T) {
    n0 <- growth(n0, data.in[3], data.in[2], data.in[1])
  };
    n0})
  )
}
```

Set your grid you want to search over, just as you did before.

```
data <- expand.grid(b = seq(0.01, 0.5, length.out=10),
                    K = exp(seq(0.1, 5, length.out=10)),
                    r = seq(0.5, 3.5, length.out=10))
initial_data = list(N0=0.9, T=5, reps=20)
```

Use apply to go through your grid, then append the results

```
output.mid = apply(data, 1, ic=initial_data, FUN=growth_runner)
output <- data.frame('n_final'=unlist(output.mid))
```

And you have your output without any calls to `do.call` or any external library.

```
> dim(output)
[1] 20000     1
> head(output)
     n_final
1 -0.6375070
2 -0.7617193
3 -0.3266347
4 -0.7921655
5 -0.5874983
6 -0.4083613
```

Comment: Sorry, you're missing critical context of the question: using dplyr. (First line of the question). The edit of 5/19 makes this clear. This is useful code though to accomplish the same overall task in a less generic way. Thanks!

Comment: Also note that `apply()` will fail as soon as you have non-numeric parameters

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the line with `do.call` with the following (Thanks to **@shorpy** for pointing out `purrr:invoke_rows()`):

```
  grouped_out <- purrr::invoke_rows(fun, dplyr::rowwise(data), fixed_parameters)
```

without any other changes, this will give a data frame with a column of data.frames, like

```
Source: local data frame [1,000 x 4]
            b        K     r                .out
        (dbl)    (dbl) (dbl)               (chr)
1  0.01000000 1.105171   0.5 <data.frame [20,1]>
2  0.06444444 1.105171   0.5 <data.frame [20,1]>
3  0.11888889 1.105171   0.5 <data.frame [20,1]>
```

To recover something closer to the original behavior, replace the final line of `run` with

```
dplyr::ungroup(tidyr::unnest(grouped_out, .out))
```

which gives

```
Source: local data frame [20,000 x 4]

       b        K     r    n_final
   (dbl)    (dbl) (dbl)      (dbl)
1   0.01 1.105171   0.5 -0.6745470
2   0.01 1.105171   0.5 -0.7500365
3   0.01 1.105171   0.5 -0.6568312
```

No other changes to the code are needed :)

Comment: I wouldn't rely on that as `invoke_rows()` may not be long for this world

Comment: thanks for the heads up! i'll look into `pmap` (as in your answer) instead